# jquery post array causing browser to hang - mvc 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I've got a JS array of the following objects:

```
function SkillModel(skillModelAdapter) {
    this.SkillId = skillModelAdapter.SkillId;
    this.SkillName = skillModelAdapter.SkillName;
    this.Proficiency = skillModelAdapter.Proficiency;

    this.Element = null;

    this.ProficiencyString = function () {
        switch (this.Proficiency) {
            case 1:
                return "Beginner";
            case 2:
                return "Novice";
            case 3:
                return "Intermediate";
            case 4:
                return "Advanced";
            default:
                return "Expert";
        }
    };

    this.CreateElement = function () {
        var searchSkill = $('<div>').addClass('searchSkill').attr('skillId', this.SkillId);
        var skillName = $('<span>').addClass('skillName').html(this.SkillName);
        var proficiency = $('<span>').attr('proficiency', this.Proficiency).html(' (' + this.ProficiencyString() + ')');
        var removeLink = $('<a href="#">').addClass('removeSkill').html('X');

        searchSkill.append(skillName);
        searchSkill.append(proficiency);
        searchSkill.append(removeLink);

        this.Element = searchSkill;

        $('#SkillsContainer').append(searchSkill);
    };
}
```

When the array is posted to my MVC controller it works fine if the array is empty. If the array has an object in it, it crashes.

Is there an issue because my json object contains functions?

Cheers,

James

Comment: Where is the code for the jquery post? "It crashes" client or server side? Exception message, stacktrace?

Comment: Hi, it crashes client side, don't get any errors except a crash screen in chrome.

Comment: @James, yes. It tries to serialize the object, and that means all properties.. but it fails when it tries to serialize the `CreateElement` property of the object.. Have a look at http://www.json.org/ to see what is allowed..

Comment: Thanks gaby that's just what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions cannot be JSON serialized. You should not be trying to serialize such object. From your code it looks like that you already are passing some `skillModelAdapter` object to the `SkillModel` constructor which looks a good candidate for JSON serializing:

For example:

```
var skillModelAdapters = [
    { SkillId: 1, SkillName: 'skill 1', Proficiency: 1 },
    { SkillId: 2, SkillName: 'skill 2', Proficiency: 1 },
    { SkillId: 3, SkillName: 'skill 3', Proficiency: 3 },
    { SkillId: 4, SkillName: 'skill 4', Proficiency: 2 }
];
```

and then:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(skillModelAdapters),
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

and on the server side you would have a view model:

```
public class SkillViewModel
{
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public string SkillName { get; set; }
    public int Proficiency { get; set; }
}
```

and a corresponding controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(IEnumerable<SkillViewModel> skills)
{
    ...
}
```